# trying to get status from db and use it in div

Tags: php, mysqli

Well, I'm trying to create a support ticket system, and this should check from the database if Status is 0 or above zero, if its zero it should say Close Ticket and if its not it should say reopen ticket, but the problem is it shows both buttons and its even printing code, i mean look :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F60CM.jpg

Code:

```
if($row > 0)
{

    $other = "SELECT * FROM `Dashboard` WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $other);
    $output = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $stanje = $row["Status"];

    echo '

    <br><div class="ticket_info">



    if($stanje == 0 ) {   <button class="lockticket" value="lockticketbutton">Close Ticket</button></a> }
    else if($stanje != 0 ) {  <button class="lockticket" value="lockticketbutton">Reopen Ticket</button></a> }

    Postavio: '.$output['Postavio'].' --- ['.$output['Naslov'].']

    </div>

    </br><div class="ticket_info2">

    '.$output['Text'].'

    </div>

    ';

    $odg = "SELECT * FROM `ticketcomments` WHERE `TicketID` = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$odg);
    while( $odgovor = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
    {

        echo '

        <br><div class="ticket_odgovor">

        Postavio: '.$odgovor['Poslao'].' --- [Odgovor na TiketID#'.$odgovor['TicketID'].']

        </div>

        </br><div class="ticket_odgovor2">

        '.$odgovor['Odgovor'].'

        </div>


        ';      
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your conditional check for the buttons inside your string you're passing to the `echo` statement.    This will not get treated as a conditional by PHP, just a string.

You can have multiple echo statements without any issue.  Try something like this:

```
echo '<br><div class="ticket_info">';
if($stanje == 0 ) {  
   echo ' <button class="lockticket" value="lockticketbutton">Close Ticket</button></a> ';
} else { 
   echo ' <button class="lockticket" value="lockticketbutton">Reopen Ticket</button></a>';   
}

 echo ...
```

Comment: yep but if i close the echo to get the data from database, how else am i going to be able to set div outside of echo ?

Comment: @Nathaniel see my example I added

Comment: Thank you, it works, one mor thing, this <button> thing how can i make it work like submit function, i need to update query with that, but if i go like this 

if(isset($_POST['lockticketbutton']))
{
}

it doesnt work, is there a way to submit a button without form ?

Answer (score 1):

Dude, you  have quotes problems, try this code:

```
if($row > 0){

$other = "SELECT * FROM `Dashboard` WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $other);
$output = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$stanje = $row["Status"];

echo '<br><div class="ticket_info">';



if($stanje == 0 ) {   
echo '<button class="lockticket" value="lockticketbutton">Close Ticket</button></a>'; }
else if($stanje != 0 ) {  
echo '<button class="lockticket" value="lockticketbutton">Reopen Ticket</button></a>'; }

echo 'Postavio: '.$output['Postavio'].' --- ['.$output['Naslov'].']</div></br><div class="ticket_info2">'.$output['Text'].'</div>';

$odg = "SELECT * FROM `ticketcomments` WHERE `TicketID` = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$odg);
while( $odgovor = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
{

    echo '

    <br><div class="ticket_odgovor">

    Postavio: '.$odgovor['Poslao'].' --- [Odgovor na TiketID#'.$odgovor['TicketID'].']

    </div>

    </br><div class="ticket_odgovor2">

    '.$odgovor['Odgovor'].'

    </div>


    ';      
}
```